# I am creating a program where i am inserting a pyramid into a pyramid of height h. However, my code seems to be lacking

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my working code. I want to use pure iteration in this that's why I purposely didn't use array and strings:

```
def print_triangles(h):
    base = 2 * h - 1
    space = base * (h-1) + (h-1)
    for _ in range(1, h+1):
        for row in range(1, h+1):
            stars = 2 * row - 1
            for _ in range(space):
                print(" ", end="")
            for _ in range(stars):
                print("*", end="")
            space = space - 1
            print()
        space = space - h + 1

h = int(input())

print_triangles(h)
```

This is what it outputs when h = 3:

```
            *
           ***
          *****
       *
      ***
     *****
  *
 ***
*****
```

However, I want it to look something like this:

```
            *
           ***
          *****
       *    *    *
      ***  ***  ***
     ***************
  *    *    *    *    *
 ***  ***  ***  ***  ***
*************************
```

Comment: unrelated:  `for _ in range(stars): print("*", end="")` == `print("*" * stars, end="")` same for  `for _ in range(space):`

Comment: Hello, it is because you are only printing out triangles on the single side with your nested for loop, you aren't drawing any other triangles. You need to also print the other triangles, with what you have you will only print one side, in a cascading fashion, you can go bigger and bigger, but it will only print the single side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing one layer of iteration and is only printing one pyramid in each layer.
Your code should be:

```
def print_triangles(h):
    base = 2 * h - 1
    for layer in range(1, h+1):
        prefix = base * (h - layer)
        for row in range(1, h+1):
            for _ in range(prefix):
                print(" ", end="")
            pyramids = layer*2 -1
            stars = 2 * row - 1
            spaces = h - row
            for pyramid in range(pyramids):
                for _ in range(spaces):
                    print(" ", end="")
                for _ in range(stars):
                    print("*", end="")
                for _ in range(spaces):
                    print(" ", end="")
            print()
```

Comment: This is what you are looking for, OP!